# Is there a way to ship nodewebkit apps with mysql?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

What i need is one file that installs my app and mysql database. I don't want that my end-users have to install it by hand.

Comment: you can put your files in an archive and use nsis to easily instal your app

Comment: you could also just use an embedded db like sqlite or leveldb

Comment: Yes it's a good solution to the problem. But sqlite has any difference from mysql in usage or otimization ?